# How to keep input file intact in Python classes

Tags: python, oop

Hi I have been facing this issue and not able to resolve it .I have written a small case to demonstrate this. I give an input "file", create a class and create "file2" using some method in the class. Now "file" has also changed and "file" and "file2" are identical.
How to keep input "file" intact.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

class check:
    def __init__(self, dat):
        self.dat= dat
    def average(self):
        dat= self.dat
        dat['average']= np.mean(dat['marks'])
        return dat



file= pd.DataFrame({"name":['a','b','c'], "marks":[12,13,14]})
file.shape#(3, 2)

Check_file= check(file)
file2= Check_file.average()

file.shape#(3, 3)
```

Comment: Use `Check_file= check(file.copy())` instead of `Check_file= check(file)`. `file` changes because the same object is referenced.

Comment: btw , you seem to be trying to return a single value which is the `avg` of `marks`. If so you don't need to modify `dat`. Just `return np.mean(dat['marks'])`

Comment: thanks sjd. This example is just made up as I cant post my real codes here. The copy thing works fine. Though I was thinking thre coud be some modification to the class to cover this issue.

Answer (score 0):

First, it's recommended to not use parentheses in your class definition if you aren't inheriting from a superclass (bad style). For your issue, try passing in a copy of the DataFrame, i.e. `Check_file= check(file.copy())`